# SQL WHERE syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

When I run:

```
$query = "UPDATE subjects SET
               menu_name = '{$menu_name}',
               position = {$position},
               visible =  {$visible},
               WHERE ID = {$ID}";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

I get back:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID = 1' at line 5

Comment: remove the comma before `where`

Answer (score 5):

Remove this comma before the `WHERE` clause. Since there are no more values to update, the comma is not needed and hence causes a syntax error.

```
visible =  {$visible},
                     ^
```